# Send an ok/cancel confirm with database data? ASP.Net VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, confirm

Can someone help me with this:

I want to send a confirm message to the user if a button is clicked. But the problem is that I want server data on the message.

For Example:

```
|¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯|
|  You are going to delete  |
| 4 messages, are you sure? |
|                           |
|   |OK|        |Cancel|    |
|___________________________|
```

The number 4 is brought from database with a Stored Procedure.
If the user clicks OK it should do some other code, if cancel is clicked, it should just return...

This is for a website on ASP.net using Visual Basic.

Please help!

**Update:**

After @T.S. answer I came up with this:

```
'Method for receiving the number...
'messages = numberReceived
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, "Confirmation", "<script> if (confirm('You will delete " & messages.ToString & " messages, are you sure?')) { ConfirmOnClean() }; </script>", False)
```

And the javascript function ConfirmOnClean() gets called correctly. What can I do to call a method on the codebehind after the user clicked OK?

**Update:**

I Finally solved it by Just adding a hidden field on the form:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="cleanStatus" Value="dontClean" runat="server" />
```

And then on the Confirm on clean function I just did:

```
function ConfirmOnClean() {
    $('#<%=cleanStatus.ClientId %>').val('clean');
    __doPostBack('<%=btnClean %>','');
}
```

And on the Page_Load method on my codebehind I added:

```
If cleanStatus.Value.Equals("clean") Then
    OnConfirm() 'Method for calling the stored procedure for deleting the messages.
End If
```

I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is lacking concrete code. So here is one option:

Assume you have some Id. You call stored proc

```
Dim message as String
Using cmd as new SqlCommand(...
    cmd.ExecuteNoQuery()
    ' retrieve your parameters here
    message = cmd.Parameters(0).Value
End Using
```

Now code returns to the user with the values you retrieved. You can register script block to show the message immediately on the page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

When user User clicks Ok, you can, for example, set a hidden field with a value and invoke `postback`. YOur aspx page will read the value and invoke DB-call to delete values.

You need to provide more details to get more concrete solution here

Comment: The problem is, I have to call the SP on the click listener. That is fine, but how do I return it to the page so it can show the data on the confirm box? And then after user input, call another method on the codebehind?

Comment: @hectorviov This is exactly what I've explained to you in the second paragraph, and provided the link where you can see how it is done. since your question doesn't have any specific code, I can't provide any specific answer.

Comment: Ok, so far I've done this: `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, "Confirmation", "<script> if (confirm('You will delete " & messages.ToString & " messages, are you sure?')) { ConfirmOnClean() }; </script>", False)` and ConfirmOnClean javascript function is called correctly. How can I call the delete method on the codebehind? @t-s can you elaborate on the postback please?

Comment: @hectorviov Hey, check this out. It is simple. http://dopostback.net/ and this http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/320_Doing_or_Raising_Postback_using___doPostBack%28%29_function_from_Javascript_in_AspNet.aspx  I actually done that in one of the applications. It works great!! I learned from these very links